# Is it a common practice to change the title into something different?

Tags: anime-production, anime-history, rurouni-kenshin

Sometimes they change the title into something different, and by different I mean it's not an English translation. An example here is *[Rurouni Kenshin](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Rurouni_Kenshin)*. Although it state that:

> Rurouni Kenshin is subtitled "Wandering Samurai" in some English releases.

which makes it the closest translation, as a rough translation of the title would be "Kenshin the Wandering Swordsman". But they also use the name *Samurai X* for this anime title.

> The English-language versions of the OVAs, as well as the film, were originally released as Samurai X in North America, although the original name was included on the later DVD and Blu-ray Disc releases.

But it's not only in North America, as they also mentioned

> Sony Pictures Television International created an English-language version of the series, titled Samurai X, that airs outside of the United States

I don't know if there's another anime that also does this, but I've never seen something like this recently.

Comment: I'm not sure but some programs, not necessarily anime, but shows like Mako Mermaids in Australia is called An h2o Adventure in other countries if that's what you mean.

Comment: It's a fairly common thing even with movies, other types of TV shows, books, etc.

Comment: Many titles are changed to attract an English audience. I mean, what sounds more interesting: Wandering Samurai, or Samurai X? Otherwise, there's an issue with the Japanese title, as it is not very attractive to an English-speaking audience. What's Rurouni Kenshin? Nobody would understand it from the tons of other Japanese-titled series. We do this to series, like Hayate no Gotoku, and change it to Combat Butler. Or Kodomo no Jinkan

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This occurs pretty often, it is called [Cultural streamlining](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Editing_of_anime_in_American_distribution#Cultural_streamlining)

> To accommodate American viewers, anime dubbed in the United States is usually modified to suggest it occurs within the United States or a fictional country thus resembling it. This is commonly achieved by substituting Japanese elements in a series by elements drawn from American popular culture, modifying food or other products to resemble their American equivalents and by replacing Japanese writing with English writing.

A very simple example as was given on the wiki is Ash from the Pokemon series carrying a sandwich in the American version while in the Japanese version he carries a onigiri

The same counts for the titles of those kind of series, aka the wandering samurai instead of Rurouni Kenshin. Because most of their audience would not even know what a Rurouni is.

Changes such as Samurai X usually are done for [audience stereotyping](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Editing_of_anime_in_American_distribution#Audience_stereotyping), a series called Wandering samurai is less likely to be watched by a female audience. While the name Samurai X is also more attractive to the female audience, which broadens their audience for more income of the series.

In the end all Renaming of characters/titles is mainly for marketing purposes.